# React MUI: How to make the css grid columns automatically wrap on the next row

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have a css grid. It contains a dynamic number of elements.
Something like this:

```
 <Box className={classes.Grid}>
                <Button variant="outlined">1</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">2</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">3</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">4</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">5</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">6</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">7</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">8</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">9</Button>
                <Button variant="outlined">10</Button>
</Box>
```

And

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    Grid: {
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
        gridGap: "10px",
        margin: "auto",
        width: "90vw",
    }
});
```

So how can I make the nr of columns on each row dependent on the size of the grid element? **Also forgot to mention that every child has a specific width/height (220px/200px)**

Comment: What do you mean "depend on the size of the grid element"? You want to not have three columns if, for instance, the first button is very wide (which would make the first row have only one item and push the others to the next row)?

Comment: Why don't you use [Grid](https://mui.com/components/grid/#main-content) component?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to have rows to fill the free space, then `@robske_110's`  answer is what you want. 
But if you want to have more control when and how much size to have, then I'd recommend making a use of `breakpoints` built in `MUI`.
Here is [the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cache-6j4it?file=/src/App.js) and example below.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    Grid: {
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
      gridGap: "10px",
      margin: "auto",
      width: "90vw",
      [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2, 1fr)"
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: So, we can create grid-based components with MUI, right?

Comment: @SalahAdDin absolutely

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for auto-fill. It automatically fills the rows with as many elements which can fit in that row.
Try

```
gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fill, 5em)"
```

You can adjust 5em to your needs.

You can combine that with the function minmax() to only define a minimum size for the buttons and let them stretch the last bit in order to fill the whole width and not only in n*button_width increments.

```
gridTemplateColumens: "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5em, 1fr))"
```

Again, adjust 5em to the width your buttons need to have at the minimum.

Here is how that would look (in plain HTML):

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 1fr));
}

.grid > div{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div>Element 1</div>
<div>Element 2</div>
<div>Element 3</div>
<div>Element 4</div>
<div>Element 5</div>
<div>Element 6</div>
<div>Element 7</div>
<div>Element 8</div>
<div>Element 9</div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns